# Find duplicate in multiple email fields

Tags: postgresql

I have a weird requirement.
I have to find duplicate contact records in my database (Should be simple), My issue is that I must match by first name, last name and ANY of the emails fields matching among themselves.

```
Exemple:
FirstName    | LastName    | Email           | WorkEmail            | AnotherEmail
John           Smith          jh@jh.com         test@test.com          yougettheIdea.com
John           Smith          test@test.com                              
John           Smith          imAdifferent.jh.com
```

I need to Identify in this example, that John Smith in row 1 and 2 are a duplicated record, but on row 3 is not.
Basically, I need to query on FirstName matching FirstName, LastName matching LastName, and any of the email fields matching any of the fields...
Is this even possible?

I got this for matching on first and last names, but the emails are too much for me:

```
SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT "FirstName","LastName","Email",","WorkEmail","AnotherEmail", count(*)
      OVER
        (PARTITION BY
          "FirstName",
          "LastName"
        ) AS count
      FROM Contact) tableWithCount
      WHERE tableWithCount.count > 1 ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build an array of the email columns and then check for duplicates by using the contains operator `@>` in both directions.

```
select *
from contact c1
where exists (select * 
              from contact c2
              where (c1.first_name, c1.last_name) = (c2.first_name, c2.last_name)
                and (    
                    array_remove(array[c1.email, c1.work_email, c1.another_email],null) @> array_remove(array[c2.email, c2.work_email, c2.another_email], null)
                 or array_remove(array[c1.email, c1.work_email, c1.another_email],null) <@ array_remove(array[c2.email, c2.work_email, c2.another_email], null) 
                )
                and c1.ctid <> c2.ctid
              );
```

The expression `c1.ctid <> c2.ctid` is used to avoid comparing a row with itself. If you have a primary or unique key in your table, use that column instead.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=64b561e4fc4e51823487a902203b6ae4)

Answer (score 0):

I would use exists logic here, checking each email column against every other column.  The following query identifies all records which do *not* have a duplicate record.

```
SELECT *
FROM Contact c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Contact c2
                  WHERE c2.LastName = c1.LastName AND c2.FirstName = c1.FirstName AND
                        c2.id <> c1.id AND  -- assuming there is a PK column id
                        (c2.Email = c1.Email OR c2.WorkEmail = c1.Email OR
                         c2.AnotherEmail = c1.Email
                         OR
                         c2.Email = c1.WorkEmail OR c2.WorkEmail = c1.WorkEmail OR
                         c2.AnotherEmail = c1.WorkEmail
                         OR
                         c2.Email = c1.AnotherEmail OR c2.WorkEmail = c1.AnotherEmail OR
                         c2.AnotherEmail = c1.AnotherEmail));
```

If you instead want to find all duplicate records, then change `NOT EXISTS` to `EXISTS`.